# Github Actions: Why an intermediate command failure in shell script would cause the whole step to fail?

Tags: bash, grep, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a step in a Github Actions job:

```
      - name: Check for changes
        run: |
          diff=$( git diff --name-only 'origin/main' )
          changed_files=$( echo $diff | grep -c src/my_folder ) # this fails

          # more script lines
          # that are unrelated
```

This fails with `Error: Process completed with exit code 1.` **only if grep finds nothing**.
If there are matches in `$diff`, then this step works as intended. But of course it also needs to work without matches.

I can run this locally or inside a script without a problem, exit code is always `0` (on a Mac).

I fail to understand what the problem is. After some hours of trial and error and research I learned that apparently `grep` is tricky in Github actions, but I found no hint or proper documentation how I am supposed to solve this exact case.

If I change my failing line to

```
echo $( echo $diff | grep -c src/my_folder ) # this works and prints out the result
```

this gets executed without problems.

**But how do I get my grep output into my variable even when there are no findings?**

Comment: sorry, a bit off topic, why not using an existing action in order to filter for file changes, like [dorny/paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun), by default Github Actions enables `set -e` to run the step's commands. This is why an intermediate command failure may cause the whole step to fail. To take full control of your step's commands you can do like this:

```yaml
  - name: Check for changes
    shell: bash {0}
    run: |
      diff=$( git diff --name-only 'origin/main' )
      changed_files=$( echo $diff | grep -c src/my_folder )

      # ...
      # ...
```

Or you can just disable the default `set -e` at the beginning of the step's script:

```yaml
  - name: Check for changes
    run: |
      set +x

      diff=$( git diff --name-only 'origin/main' )
      changed_files=$( echo $diff | grep -c src/my_folder )

      # ...
      # ...
```

Comment: This solved my problem, and is a good thing to know! I didn't figure out why my command behaves different when run by Github Actions (yet), but with `shell: bash {0}` my shell doesn't stumble over it anymore. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped. i myself prefer the `bash {0}` way. no surprise any more. :)

Comment: I was wondering if it is actually safe to rely on GitHub using `set -e` semantics automatically. I was trying to find something on it in the documentation. What I found actually seems to state the opposite (`set -e` is not applied by default), which is odd. I'm trying to clarify that in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75419587/1804173).

Comment: @bluenote10 see the doc: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what problem `grep` has in Github actions but you can try something like :

```bash
... 
changed_files=$( [ ! -e $diff ] && { echo $diff | grep -c src/my_folder } || echo 0 ) 
...
```

This way grep wouldn't run if $diff is empty. It would just store 0 in `$changed_files`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [dorny/paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) action, like:

```
- uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
  id: changes
  with:
    filters: |
      src:
        - 'src/my_folder/**'

  # run only if some file in 'src/my_folder' folder was changed
- if: steps.changes.outputs.src == 'true'
  run: ...
```

Check the [output](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter#outputs) section for details about changes

Comment: This might be a last resort. I prefer to keep things as simple as I can, which is why I prefer bash. This way everything is under my control and there is as little overhead as possible. So, while this might solve the problem, I'd still be interested in how to get `grep` to work as intended...