# Error: Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: github-actions

I have been trying to automate and to update the authors.md whenever there is a new pull request and update it using the github action and below is the code for it

```
name: Add Contributor to AUTHORS.md
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  add_contributor:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Check if contributor already exists
        id: check_contributor
        run: |
          exists=$(grep -c -F "$GITHUB_ACTOR" AUTHORS.md)
          if [[ $exists -gt 0 ]]; then
            echo "exists=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "exists=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi
      - name: Get contributor's full name
        id: get_full_name
        if: steps.check_contributor.outputs.exists == 'false'
        run: |
          username=$GITHUB_ACTOR
          access_token=$GITHUB_TOKEN
          full_name=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token $access_token" "https://api.github.com/users/$username" | jq -r '.name')
          if [[ -z "$full_name" ]]; then
            full_name=$username
          fi
          echo "full_name=$full_name" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Append contributor to AUTHORS.md
        id: append_contributor
        if: steps.check_contributor.outputs.exists == 'false'
        run: |
          echo "| $full_name | $GITHUB_ACTOR |" >> AUTHORS.md
      - name: Commit and push changes
        if: steps.check_contributor.outputs.exists == 'false'
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add AUTHORS.md
          git commit -m "Add $GITHUB_ACTOR to AUTHORS.md"
          git push
```

but the github action is failing at the line  `exists=$(grep -c -F "$GITHUB_ACTOR" AUTHORS.md)`, can someone help and tell me how to resolve it

error i am getting

```
Run exists=$(grep -c -F "$GITHUB_ACTOR" AUTHORS.md)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

UPDATES:

```
name: Add Contributor to AUTHORS.md
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize

jobs:
  add_contributor:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Check if contributor already exists
        id: check_contributor
        run: |
          exists=$(grep -c -F "$GITHUB_ACTOR" AUTHORS.md)
          if [[ $exists -gt 0 ]]; then
            echo "exists=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "exists=false" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          fi
      - name: Get contributor's full name
        id: get_full_name
        if: steps.check_contributor.outputs.exists == 'false'
        run: |
          username=$GITHUB_ACTOR
          access_token=$GITHUB_TOKEN
          full_name=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: token $access_token" "https://api.github.com/users/$username" | jq -r '.name')
          if [[ -z "$full_name" ]]; then
            full_name=$username
          fi
          echo "full_name=$full_name" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Append contributor to AUTHORS.md
        id: append_contributor
        if: steps.check_contributor.outputs.exists == 'false'
        run: |
          full_name=${{ steps.get_full_name.outputs.full_name }}
          echo "| $full_name | $GITHUB_ACTOR |" >> AUTHORS.md
      - name: Commit and push changes
        if: steps.check_contributor.outputs.exists == 'false'
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add AUTHORS.md
          git commit -m "Add $GITHUB_ACTOR to AUTHORS.md"
          git push
```

try to do some changes and also tried set+x method it is not working so removed it .

also tried to store to github outputs

Comment: That must be exiting with a non-zero exit status in the absence of `$GITHUB_ACTOR` in `AUTHORS.md` due to the default Bash configuration, see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell. Using it directly inside `if` should fix this. Or, you can append `|| true` after that command and that'll be fine too.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330660/preventing-grep-from-causing-premature-termination-of-bash-e-script.

Comment: Same goes for all the other commands in your workflow where the output is being assigned to a variable. You need to handle it for those instances too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github Actions: Why an intermediate command failure in shell script would cause the whole step to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73066461/github-actions-why-an-intermediate-command-failure-in-shell-script-would-cause)

Comment: still not able to understand what need to be done in my code TO REMOVE the error .

Comment: Simply add `set +x` as the first line under `run` sections as mentioned in the above thread. That's one simple alternative that you can use.

Comment: so i need to add it for all the run commands of all steps i am doing , right

Comment: Yes, wherever you have `variable=$(command)`. Or, you may configure Bash and add a default for all `run` sections at workflow or job level. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun.

Comment: okk i will try the changes and run the github actions again and let see if anymore error comes or not.

Comment: done the cahnges suggested by you but it is still not working

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you tried under an UPDATE heading.

Comment: That's the same workflow. Only change I see is the replacement of `GITHUB_ENV` with `GITHUB_OUTPUT`.

Comment: i have also added the below line 
 full_name=${{ steps.get_full_name.outputs.full_name }
as it is also creating error as it was not accesible at that step, not able to find any other issue in my code then the changes i have done , means only 2 issues .

and also tried the method of set +x but still same error so i have removed it

Comment: That's part of how output parameter works. You need to add the shell related changes in your question. Without that it's hard to say anything.

Comment: Instead of `exists=$(grep -c -F "$GITHUB_ACTOR" AUTHORS.md)`, use the command directly in `if` i.e. `if grep -c -F "$GITHUB_ACTOR" AUTHORS.md; then` and it should work.